# Capturing then printing color-accurate images

Tags: color, color-management, color-correction, shooting-technique, reproduction

I want to take photos of a few surfaces (wood floors, bricks, etc.) then print them, matching the colors of the actual object (in whatever the lighting conditions are at the moment) as closely as I am able. (I'm building scale models of things.) I don't have any professional photography equipment, just an old point-and-shoot and I guess my phone. Fwiw, neither of my cameras provide raw image files.

I *do* have an accurately-enough calibrated monitor and printer. Currently both are set up to render AdobeRGB color data. I tested the printer by printing a variety of pantone color swatches and comparing them to physical paint samples of the same color. The paper I'm printing on is satisfactorily white and opaque, and the printer calibration covers the printer + paper.

But, I'm not sure how to *capture* the colors accurately with the camera. I'm also not sure how to identify and/or control the color space of the image the camera stores ([unnecessary diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5MyL.png), not worth inlining).

Now, I don't need super high accuracy, just... decently close.

What I am *thinking* of doing is:

1. Print a small card with cyan, magenta, yellow, and black gradient strips, each fading to white.
2. Place the gradient card in the shot.
3. Set camera white balance to auto, I guess?
4. Adjust camera settings to get histogram as wide as possible without clipping blacks or whites.
5. Take picture.
6. Then, in software, tweak the image until the gradients on the card are correct (according to the software, not the monitor + my eyes), making sure to work and save in the AdobeRGB space.
7. Print.

So my questions are:

- Will that work? It seems like it *should*, except:

  - I feel like my step 6 somehow "cancels out" the ambient lighting conditions (like... since I'm taking a known color, exposing it to arbitrary lighting, then transforming the whole image back to that known color... I can't really explain why I think this it's just a gut feeling... and maybe it's what I want to do anyways since if I print that then view the printout in the same lighting conditions, then that gets reapplied? Although the white balance messes up the lighting anyways... I wish I could state this in a more sensical way :S ).
- Is there an easier way given equipment limitations?
- How is it normally done (if I had access to better cameras, color measuring thingies, etc.)?

Comment: All I can think to say is, "Oh, if only it were that simple". ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Dammit. The entire time I was writing that I was thinking "Wait... am I basically just asking somebody to explain one of the most fundamental arts of photography?" Sort of like the time one of my buddies asked me (I'm a woodworker), "how do I keep the furniture I make from warping?", and all I could say was "well, I mean... that's basically most of what woodworking *is*...".

Comment: Kind of. First of all, measuring colour by eye is really, *really* difficult. 2nd, you don't actually know how good [read 'flat'] your lighting is, then you don't know what your camera will do to that. You can't print from AdobeRGB to CMYK with anything other than guesswork & you then look at the print in more uncalibrated lighting. It's tough.

Comment: What photo editing program(s) do you have? I'm thinking you could do a post processing white balance adjustment by shooting a calibrated grey card. Better is Macbeth chart color calibration.

Comment: @qrk RawTherapee and Paint Shop Pro, and the ImageMagick command line set. I can do that adjustment. I just looked up Macbeth color charts. Found a lot of useful stuff (I also know somebody with an X-Rite ColorChecker card set now that I think about it and found some color correction tools designed for it).  Thanks.

Comment: (The thing I just learned there ^ was that automatic correction from color cards is already a thing, and the cards and tools exist, so if I can access them, I can save myself some tedious guesswork and ditch my own not-quite-so-great reinvented wheel. And as for end-to-end accuracy and lighting I guess all I can do is try it and see if it works out.)

Comment: @Tetsujin Without being able to measure it, do you think the backlight from an LCD TV (sans LCD panel and diffuser) would have a decently flat spectrum? I have one here, I don't know what kind of lamp it is, but it's got lots of glass tubes and high voltage, ‍♂️.

Comment: Again, it's an unknown. Lighting can be measured for accuracy using a structure known as CRI [Colour Rendering Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index) which is another minefield ;)

Comment: No joke about this being a can of worms. Another problem is I thought my printer calibration was OK but turns out its only good for darker colors, mostly because the cyan toner is significantly darker than AdobeRGB / sRGB / ProPhotoRGB's pure cyan (e.g. I wouldn't be able to print the color of a blue or green highlighter pen); which isn't even in the Pantone space apparently, and now I've lost confidence in the printer mfr's internal device profile, and gained a lot of confusion about the range of consumer printer color gamuts. Magenta has a similar issue but not as drastic.

Comment: (Although, one small success on the capturing end of things is white balancing with a gray card significantly improved the accuracy. It's still not sufficiently accurate but it seems to give me more wiggle room with lighting spectral flatness. Also RawTherapee has some "automatic exposure compensation" algorithm, I don't know the details but whatever magic it does seems to help a lot as well, or at least, doing it first helps the white balance correction be more effective.)

Comment: Printers simply **cannot** reproduce even the relatively limited gamut of sRGB, let alone Adobe RGB or Pro RGB [which actually goes outside human perception & cannot be even reproduced on a screen]

Comment: @Tetsujin, CRI is only a minefield with LED's and fluorescent sources. With Tungsten, Carbon Arc, or Xeon, CRI is at (or near enough) 100. There's still the problem of color temperature, but that's a different problem. CRI describes how much of the visible spectrum is present (or more importantly missing).

Comment: I bought a nix mini 2 (they're on sale rn btw) that may or may not be helpful. I figure maybe I can use it to measure real life colors and use them as correction data points. Should have it next week.

Answer (score 2):

Lighting is the place to start. You want a very high CRI for color critical work. Tungsten hot lights are the most accessible way to get that.

Second piece is an accurate gray card.

Third piece is a camera that allows setting the white balance off the gray card.

But with a good tungsten bulb, the color temperature will be right at 3200k.

If you use LED’s or fluorescent sources, you won’t have full spectrum and some colors will always be off. Xenon flash/strobe tends to have some variation in temperature, though it provides full spectrum.

Without a known light source, everything  about the input is more of a guess.

Light sources for viewing printed colors is a whole higher level of specialized equipment with prices to match. But that’s a mostly a waste of resources without accurate input.

Comment: When taking the photo, does calibrating against a white + gray + black card compensate for nonideal lighting? Under the assumption that the spectral *coverage* of the light is fairly complete I mean (as in, not sodium vapor lamps or something like that).

Comment: Actually does the lighting even need to be full visible spectrum or does it just need to cover the combined spectrum of the camera sensor elements? This might be a separate question.

Comment: @Jason C If the light is not full spectrum, materials can not reflect the missing frequencies. The human visual system (our eyes) can and do see colors in the gaps do to the way out visual experience is constructed by our nervous system. On the camera, all visible frequencies can be defined in terms of red, green, and blue (or X,Y,Z in the general case). The science of human visual experience is complicated, messy, and wet. But it is a science.

Comment: Thanks!! That's actually not *quite* what I meant in 2nd q, but I don't really know how to explain what I meant and I am pretty sure it was a stupid question anyway, so yeah ... Lol. Basically I wasn't sure if camera sensors were some weird subset of visible light, i.e. is there a difference between "full" spectrum vs some minimal spectrum that matches the camera sensor response spectrum... and that q ultimately leads to "can I find cheaper lighting that's good enough". It might've been unclear because it's a super naive question that is probably a given.

Comment: Like... if hypothetically, there's like super expensive research-grade full uniform spectrum calibration-certificate-included lighting vs reasonably priced less-perfect lighting that still looks the same to a typical camera.

Comment: @JasonC Tungsten hot lights are not expensive and because there are sensible tradeoffs favoring LED for many applications, used tungsten fixtures are even cheaper.

Comment: @JasonC camera sensors are sensitive to the entire visible spectrum as well as adjacent parts of the UV and IR. Typically digital camera sensors have a band pass filter to exclude UV and IR frequencies. The band pass filter is often called a hot mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer a lot but if you want the most accurate color you can also buy a color card, something like the X-rite color checker card. Then once you get your images into Lightroom / Photoshop, you can color balance your way back to reality. If you had a scanner you could scan the X-rite color card, and get even closer by using a color picker to pick colors in each, or by comparing histograms. Working in RAW would obviously give you a lot more latitude for transforming the color of the image, without causing software artifacts which are exacerbated by compression.

If you can't afford a RAW workflow just yet, you can maximize the color range you capture by setting your white balance as closely as possible to reality. However setting it accurately is also some amount of guesswork because, unless you are working in the perfect darkness of a studio, you won't know the color of your ambient light sources. You could also get a color meter but that's a hefty investment.

Your cheapest solution would be to get yourself into a RAW capable camera, and get a color card.

Comment: The color checker card is premised on high CRI lighting. Of course if the work is not really color critical, then lower CRI may be good enough. And good enough is good enough. That’s probably really the case here.

Comment: True, but if he scanned the color card, and his camera-scanner-PSD were all in sync, then the scan of the card will be his true to life reference point. CRI / Light source quality won't matter (except from the standpoint of capturing more dynamic range)

Comment: I'm not sure how scanning a colour passport is going to aid this workflow. No scan is needed for the workflow, so it's just introducing another random variable. Also, setting white-balance is going to be of zero effect if the light source has 'holes' in it.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to make a simple list. I will try to explain more later.

**Camera, taking the image**

1. Light
2. Exposition
3. White balance
4. Calibration

**Processing**

5. Monitor and view conditions

**Print**

6. Printer calibration
7. Material consistency
8. Manually adjusting variables to the print.